# Relative Hurewicz Theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

For a given zero-reduced simply connected simplicial set $X$, one can define simplicial group $GX$ representing the loop space of $X$, its Abelianization $AX = GX/[GX,GX]$ and show that the map induced by the Abelianization $h_*: \pi_{n+1}(X)=\pi_n(GX)\to \pi_n(AX)=H_{n+1}(X)$ corresponds to the Hurewicz homomorphism. Groups $\pi_n(GX)$, $\pi_n(AX)$ are defined as homology groups of the Moore complex of $GX$ and $AX$, respectively. (References for Moore complexes and the combinatorial definition of $\pi_n$ are, for example, [Kan: A Combinatorial Definition of Homotopy Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970006) or [May: Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo5956688.html).)

We ask whether the same result can be obtained in the relative case for a pair $(X,K)$, where $K$ is a subcomplex of $X$. Then it is easy to define $\pi_n(AX,AK) \cong H_{n+1}(X,K)$ as the homology of the relative Moore complex. However, there is a problem to define "$\pi_n(GX, GK) \cong \pi_{n+1}(X,K)$" on the level of Moore complexes due to noncommutativity: relative homology of $(GX,GK)$ is not clearly defined.

Any hints and references are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe turn the map $i\colon GK\to GX$ into a homotopy equivalent fibration $i'\colon G'K \twoheadrightarrow GX$ , and define $\pi_n(X, K)=\pi_{n-1}(\ker i')$? Passing to abelianizations, you seem to get a compatible model for relative homology.